# Convertir codigo java a c#

Tags: java, c#, .net, wpf

Buenos días.

Me han pasado una aplicación de escritorio en java para convertirla a WPF (c#). No conozco mucho de java pero intuyendo lo que hace, poco a poco la he conseguido traducir a excepción de un bloque de código. El código es el siguiente:

```
string key = "CLAVEPARACONVERSION";
string base64EncryptedString = "";
string text = "Esta es la cadena de texto que se va a codificar";

MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
byte[] digestOfPassword = md.digest(key.getBytes("utf-8"));
byte[] keyBytes = Arrays.copyOf(digestOfPassword, 24);

SecretKey key = new SecretKeySpec(keyBytes, "DESede");
Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("DESede");
cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);

byte[] plainTextBytes = text.getBytes("utf-8");
byte[] buf = cipher.doFinal(plainTextBytes);
byte[] base64Bytes = Base64.encodeBase64(buf);
base64EncryptedString = new String(base64Bytes);
```

¿Alguien me puede echar una mano? Lo agradecería muchísimo.
Un saludo y gracias de antemano.

Comment: ¿Qué excepciones o errores te manda? ¿Qué código has intentado convertir a C#? Recuerda que entre más detalles proporciones, será más fácil encontrar la solución a tu problema ;)

Comment: No manda ni errores ni excepciones. Basicamente no se como convertir ese codigo en java a codigo c#, la equivalencia en c# de las clases MessageDigest, SecretKeySpec y Cipher de java.

Comment: Creo que para la clase MessageDigest el equivalente es  [HashAlgorithm](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.hashalgorithm.aspx), los demás no estoy seguro.

Comment: @Alejandro, una alternativa puede ser: si sabes qué hace este código, intenta hacerlo en C# - *(independientemente de cómo esté hecho en Java)*. También intenta buscar por ejemplo: `SecretKeySpec c# equivalent` en Google y así con cada clase que desconozcas.

Comment: Gracias a todos por vuestras respuestas. Al final vi que el algoritmo era un 3DES y busque el algoritmo para C# y funciono correctamente.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El codigo que aparece ahi es de una funcion de encripcion y desencripcion, para usarla en .NET debe usar  la libreria System.Security.Cryptography

En este link encontrara un ejemplo para el algoritmo 3DES (DESede) que esta en el codigo java (pagina en ingles)

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36529337/3des-desede-decrypt-encrypted-text-done-by-java-in-c-sharp

Vea tambien la descripcion del metodo de encripcion y desencripcion del MSDN:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.tripledescryptoserviceprovider.aspx#Examples

Si esto le sirve como respuesta por favor marquelo